# How to trigger email for every check-out in EME - Ab Initio

Tags: ab-initio

I would like to create a new notification email with each checkout in EME (Enterprise Meta Environment). I have been searching the web for a valid lead but I didn't come across any blogs or article.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you are using GDE or you are using air commands to check out. 
If you are using a air commands then its straight farward. Write a generic checkout script and add a mailx command after the air commands. Ask your team to use this generic script for all check out check-in tasks :)